What are the little bulges on the tail of an F-18 for?
I noticed on this photo of an F-18 from Wikipedia that the tail of this F-18 Super Hornet has multiple small bulges on it and I was wondering if anyone knows what the purpose of those bulges are?

As visible in the following cutaway (numbers E77 to E80 and F14 - cutaway source), we find:
On the right vertical stabiliser, top down:

Position light
ALQ-214 aft low/high-band receiving antenna
ALR-67 aft receiving antenna
Fuel dump outlet

On the left vertical stabiliser, top down:

ALQ-214 high-band transmitter antenna
ALQ-214 low-band transmitter antenna
ALR-67 aft receiving antenna

The ALQ-214 is a jammer (brochure, pdf) while the ALR-67 is a radar warning system. Note that the ALQ-214 consists also in a forward transmitter antenna (E35) located on the leading edge of the left strake. "Fuel dump outlet" should be self-explanatory 


They are antennas
This is the F/A-18A, but mostly the same as your depicted F model.

A Swiss C model:

From https://www.aircraftrecognitionguide.com/mcdonnell-douglas-f-18
